# Add new columns and add values from another DataFrame based on a filter

Tags: python, pandas

Add new columns and add values from another DataFrame based on a filter:

I have two DataFrames as follows:
infra_df:-

```
    Name   time  
    net    8am
    stat   8am
    net    8am
    net    8am
    sig    8am
    net    8am
```

measures_df:-

```
    tcp_time.  tcp_wait   
    12         33
    22         11
    23         32
    34         11
```

Now I want to add columns from measures_df to infra_df for rows wherever Name is net and NAN everywhere else:-

result_df:-

```
    Name   time   tcp_time   tcp_wait
    net    8am    12         33
    stat   8am    NAN        NAN
    net    8am    22         11
    net    8am    23         32
    sig    8am    NAN        NAN
    net    8am    34         11
```

Comment: So you are assuming the measures_df will have the same number of rows as infra_df has net rows?

Comment: yes. but after excluding NANs in measures_df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If length of measures_df is same like number of `net` values in `infra_df` use:

```
m = infra_df['Name'].eq('net')
df = pd.concat([infra_df, measures_df.set_index(m.index[m])], axis=1)
print (df)
   Name time  tcp_time.  tcp_wait
0   net  8am       12.0      33.0
1  stat  8am        NaN       NaN
2   net  8am       22.0      11.0
3   net  8am       23.0      32.0
4   sig  8am        NaN       NaN
5   net  8am       34.0      11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The index of the examples with net as Name:

```
idx = intra_df.loc[intra_df["Name"].eq("net")].index
```

We concat with measures_df with a modified index:

```
intra_df = pd.concat([intra_df, measures_df.iloc[:len(idx),:].set_index(idx)], axis=1)
```

I also added iloc in case there would be more rows in measures_df than net in intra_df.

.dropna() drops all the nan rows if that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both the answer worked for me